# How to update all fields but one certain field statement in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, except

Suppose I have a table '**tbl**' with 4-field schema: **f1,f2,f3,f4**. I have bunch of data (in csv form whose list order of fields are same as table schema's [cause I design it] but leave the field-f3 value as ',,' in csv)  needed to correct from my users but only leave f3 unchanged. I image there's such an update statement as:

```
UPDATE tbl VALUES ('new-f1-val','new-f2-val', IGNORE, 'new-f3-val')
```

where when db engine sees this statement, it will recognize **IGNORE** as a system predefined reserved word/constant that tells db engine to ignore (i.e. NOT TO) updating this particular field. I'm not telling fairy tale cause I constantly face these needs from my users.

Is there such statement in MySQL, whether current or future, or any equivalent statements/procedures to achieve same result?

==================================

Many people don't understand why I image this kind of statement, so I'll tell my practical motivation here:

1. table 'tbl' might have many fields.
2. **Not to update field 'f3'** is permanent condition.
3. **No information about what other fields may be needed to correct**, so I'm to update all other fields.
4. I hope to make update statement short.
5. I hope there's an update statement pretty much like the insert
   statement without listing each field name out.
6. If such statement exists, I can save efforts to modify my
   "creating-insert-statement' codes to 'updating-update-statement'codes.

==================================

EDIT:
I add description of file format of data that users gave me to refine my question.

==================================

Comment: Why don't you use `UPDATE tbl set f1='new-f1-val', f2='new-f2-val'` style update?

Comment: do you have any condition in, in which you don't wish to update f3?

Comment: **@krishna**: Yes, "not to update f3" is permanent condition. **@sphere**:I don't want to list each other fields since the table may have many fields and it's kinda tedious. In one word. If there's such a statement, I can easily modify my "creating-insert-statement" codes to "creating-update-statement" codes easily, practically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **always** explicitly add the columns you want to update in a table, it's good practice, your need for shortening the query notwithstanding. 
That being said,  try inserting "null" and checking if it works. No guarantee here, haven't tried so myself.

Comment: Good. Please accept an answer and close the question. Update when you get a result.

Answer (score 3):

I've never seen an `UPDATE` written the way you have it in MySQL.  A typical `UPDATE` along the lines of what you want you want would look something like this:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET f1 = 'new-f1-val',
    f2 = 'new-f2-val',
    f4 = 'new-f4-val'
WHERE <some condition>
```

If you don't want to modify the `f3` column, then just leave it out of your `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: I know but my purpose is to save the work to list each other fields. Thanks anyway for answering.

Comment: @ScottChu Your comment makes no sense to me.  Please show us the table you start with, and how you want it to look after the `UPDATE`.

Comment: I wish to make statement short without list each other field name explicitly. I hope there's some update pretty mcuh like the insert statemnt without listing field list. Hope this explain my motivation. Another reason is about save effort to modify program codes as I reply to **sphere** in comment.

Answer (score 2):

Check out for update query syntax.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

```
Update tbl set f1=new-f1-val, f2=new-f2-val, f4=new-f4-val
```

Comment: I'm very familiar with update statement. I just don't want to list each other fields one by one. Please refer to my reply in comments to krishna and sphere.

Comment: You are already listing the values one by one anyways. This way, youre merely adding the fields you want the values to be explicitly assigned to.

Comment: I just make an example. The actual case may have many fields. I've update  my question to tell people about my motivation. Sorry bothering you.